# parsing json file in unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I can't parse JSON in Unity.  Here is the JSON file:

```
{
  "play_classic": [
    { "english": "PLAY CLASSIC" },
    { "spanish": "JUEGO CLÁSICO" },
    { "portuguese": "JUEGO CLÁSICO" },
    { "russian": "IGRAT' V KLASSICHESKUYU" }
  ]
}
```

the structure and code looks like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
    class Root
    {
        public List<PlayClassicData> play_classic { get; set; }  
    }



[System.Serializable]
    class PlayClassicData
    {

        public string english { get; set; }

        public string spanish { get; set; }

        public string portuguese { get; set; }

        public string russian { get; set; }
    }
```

the implementation looks like this:

`ParseJson` class:

```
 public void Deserialize()
        {
string path = Application.dataPath + "path...";
        
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            Root classic = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json);
            //Root classic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
            Debug.Log("english:" + classic.play_classic[0].english);
            Debug.Log("spanish:" + classic.play_classic[0].spanish);
       }
}
```

The code throws an error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Assets.Scripts.Infastructure.PARSER.ParseJson.Deserialize () (at Assets/Scripts/Infastructure/PARSER/ParseJson.cs:23)
```

Comment: i didnt add whole code.

Comment: You might btw want to not use the built-in `JsonUtility` here but rather use e.g. `Newtonsoft .NET JSON` -> it supports [(de)serialization of **Dictionary**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm) so you could actually have `public Dictionary<string, string> play_classic = new Dictionary<string, string>();` and could easily extend it dynamically in your JSON file ...

Comment: Also JsonUtility doesn't support properties .. you want to use fields by removing all the `{get; set}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. Wrong `Root`. It should be`public List<PlayClassicData> play_classic { get; set; }`
2. Indexing. `classic._playClassicData[0].spanish` is empty. It's the 2nd element that has the spanish value: `classic._playClassicData[1].spanish);`

Fixed `Root`:

```
class Root
{
   public List<PlayClassicData> play_classic { get; set; } 
}
```

Demo:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("example1.json");
var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
Console.WriteLine(o.play_classic[0].english);
Console.WriteLine(o.play_classic[1].spanish);
```

This prints:

```
PLAY CLASSIC
JUEGO CLÁSICO
```

I've used `System.Json.Text.JsonSerializer` but with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);` the result is the same.

Comment: i changed still same error

Comment: a. Does `json` have the expected text? b. `JsonUtility.FromJson` that's where your null exception is. Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json)`.

Comment: it is only works with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>...this is unity

Comment: Note that `System.Json.Text.JsonSerializer` is not available in Unity which uses `.Net Framework 4.x`, Unity's built-in JsonUtility and in general the serializer doesn't support properties. You want to convert them to fields by removing the `{get; set;}`

Answer (score 2):

Your Json does not match your data

```
public PlayClassicData[] _playClassicData { get; set; }
```

Should be:

```
public List<PlayClassic> play_classic { get; set; }
```

so `classic._playClassicData` is probebly `null`

Edit:

As derHugo pointed out:

Unity's built-in JsonUtility doesn't support properties.. you want to use fields by removing all the `{get; set;}`

Should be:

```
public List<PlayClassic> play_classic;
```

Comment: i added list instead of array same error nothing is change.

Comment: Not only the list and array are different but the name on the property does not match the name in the json

Comment: i changed the name of list again same error.

Comment: Unity's built-in JsonUtility doesn't support properties.. you want to use fields by removing all the `{get; set;}`

Answer (score 2):

I will assume the Json Is the representation of a traduction in multiple language. and can have multiple sentence/label translated in a return.
And you don't want a class for `play_classic` and for `play_hard`, that will hold the same Language properties. Especially not if adding a language force you to add a property in your frontend and in each and every class.

```
{
    "play_classic": [
        { "english": "PLAY CLASSIC" },
        { "spanish": "JUEGO CLÁSICO" },
        { "portuguese": "JUEGO CLÁSICO" },
        { "russian": "IGRAT' V KLASSICHESKUYU" }
    ],
    "play": [
        { "english": "PLAY" },
        { "spanish": "JUEGO" },
        { "portuguese": "JUEGO" },
        { "russian": "IGRAT'" }
    ],
    "classic": [
        { "english": "CLASSIC" },
        { "spanish": "CLÁSICO" },
        { "portuguese": "CLÁSICO" },
        { "russian": "KLASSICHESKUYU" }
    ]
}
```

I will choose `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>` as destination object. And will flattern the inner list like : `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`.
Note: You will have to additionally install/import `Newtonsoft .Net JSON` into your project since the built-in `JsonUtility` doesn't support Dictionary.
Comment by derHugo, user:7111561

```
var resultRaw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(input);

var resultFlattern = resultRaw.ToDictionary(
                                x => x.Key, 
                                x=> x.Value.SelectMany(trd=> trd)
                                .ToDictionary(kvp=> kvp.Key, kvp=> kvp.Value)
                            );
```

Usage :  given the button play_classic and the langue "portuguese"
Direct access will be as simple as
`resultFlattern[buttonName][language]`

```
var buttonName="play_classic"; var language= "portuguese";

if(resultFlattern.TryGetValue(buttonName, out Dictionary<string, string>  allTrads))
{
    if(allTrads.TryGetValue(language, out string traduction)){
        Console.WriteLine($"Traduction for button [{buttonName}] in [{language}] is : [{traduction}]") ;
    }
    else{
        Console.WriteLine($"Cant find tanslation for button : [{buttonName}] in [{language}]") ;
    }
}
else{ 
    Console.WriteLine($"Cant find tanslation for button : [{buttonName}]");
}
```

Demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/FcxtUp

I will wrap that into a nice helper that load all traductions only once.  And give the translation for a given language and button/label. Il will also fire proof it with a default return to Label name when the traduction is not found.

If language is not something easy to cahnge you can faltern the resul one more time and only keep one translation in `Dictionary<string, string>`. LabelName/Translation

Comment: Nice example and solution.

Comment: Note that for this you have to additionally install/import `Newtonsoft .Net JSON` into your project since the built-in `JsonUtility` doesn't support `Dictionary` ;) .. in general note that for this kind of localization the usage of a `.CSV` is way more convenient though ;)

Comment: @derHugo, there was an `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);` in OP code and Op had a comment like "_it is only works with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>`...this is unity_". I assume it was available.

Comment: Added your comment into the answer, with proper attribution.

Comment: @Self oh didn't note that. I stand corrected ;) seems that OP already did that (or Unity imports that package by default in newer versions)